# How to print hyperlinks inside <p> tag when databinding AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using a controller to convert any web links inside an `<input>` tag, and show them in a `<p>` tag. I want it to show the links in a hyperlink format as in 
https://www.w3schools.com is great but it shows

[image]

Here's my code,

my HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row" style=" margin-top:70px;">

    <div id='dv1'>
             <form> 

                <input ng-model="comment.txtcomment" id="txtcomment" style='width:500px' >
                <button ng-click="addComment()" style='margin-top:10px;'>Post Comment</button>
             </form> 

            <!--displaying comments-->
            <h4>Comments</h4>
                  <p>{{myText}}</p>

    </div>
    <div></div>
```

my controller

```
(function(){
    angular.module('StayFit')
    .controller('CommentController',['$scope','$state','$http', function($scope,$state,$http){
        $scope.user=JSON.parse(localStorage['User-Data']) || undefined;
        console.log( $scope.user.data);
        $scope.comment={};

        $scope.addComment=function(){
      var text=$scope.comment.txtcomment;  

      //this code will identify any links  
      var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
      var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
      var val=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
      $scope.myText=val;

        }//.error(function(error){console.log(error);});
    }])}());



      Tried using ng-binding-html, also doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently want to use text as HTML, not text, so you need to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Be aware that [SCE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) comes into play as well, so you will have to use something like `$scope.myTextVal = $sce.trustAsHtml(val);`.

Comment: changed it like this <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p> gives me this error Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context. andnow the p tag has no value

Comment: You will also need to use $sce service. I've updated my answer.